# Next.js - How to return JSON instead of HTML pre-rendered page

Tags: json, next.js

First I need to say, that I'm new to Next.js.
I'm sure it is a simple question, but perhaps I have taken the wrong approach. If so, please let me know. I already googled some stuff, but nothing provided me a working solution.

I have a page which shows some basic data. That page is available under the URL `/markets/[market]`.

In this page I want to load some current information about this market with an ajax request.
This is the code of this page:

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function Market(props) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [market,setMarket] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.market) {
            setMarket(JSON.parse(props.market));
            console.log(JSON.parse(props.market));
        }
    },[props]);

    
    const { data, error } = useSWR(
        '/markets/data/' + router.query.market,
        fetcher
    );

    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return <div>Failed to load.</div>;
    }
    if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;

    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see the data is being fetched from `/markets/data/[market]`.
I already managed, that this page gets no default layout applied. So the output is `json` format:

[image]

But the output looks like JSON-format but is `HTML` due to server pre-rendering.

[image]

How can I switch the output to JSON instead of HTML.

For completness here is the code of the page `/markets/data/[market]`.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function MarketData(props) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [prices, setPrices] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.prices) {
            setPrices(JSON.parse(props.prices));
            console.log(JSON.parse(props.prices));
        }
    },[props]);

  return JSON.stringify({
    market: {
        name: router.query.market,
        prices: props.prices
    }
  });
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    // fetch some stuff and return it
    return {
        props: { 
            prices: JSON.stringify(got),
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution to my issue:

```
export default function MarketData(props) {
    return (
        <></>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res, resolvedUrl }) => {
    ...
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.write('{\"market\": "' + market + '", "prices": ' + JSON.stringify(got) + '}');
    res.end();
    return {
        props: {},
    };
}
```

Set the content type to `application/json` and return the data with `write`.

**IMPORTANT:** You need to return an Javascript object even this code is not beeing reached at the end of the function!

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version, if you use **App Router**, you can use **Route Handlers** (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) which is designed to deal with outputting `data` response.

For example, if I want to access `/data` that gives some JSON response, I can create a route file (`app/data/route.js`) with the following code:

```
// for method GET
export async function GET() {
    var data = {
        message: 'result from get'
    }

    return Response.json({ data })
}

// for method POST
export async function POST() {
    var data = {
        message: 'result from post'
    }

    return Response.json({ data })
}
```

The solution above is similar to **API Routes** (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes) of the non **App Router**. By similar I mean they skip layout.

I think "API Routes" still works for the **App Router**